# How to stop keyboard functions from firing when the letters are typed in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script which fires scrolling to next/prev when "N" and "P" keys on keyboard are pressed. My question is how to stop this from firing when the user type these letters normally in any form (such as search field, login field, and so on.) because when I press n e.g. John in a form it does not write N instead it fires the scroll function. How to fix that behaviour?

My code is below:

```
$(document).keydown(function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 78) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        scrollToNew();
    } else if (evt.keyCode == 80) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        scrollToLast();
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The event object has a `target` property which tells you where the event actually occurred (after which it bubbled up to your document-level handler). So you can test `evt.target` against form field elements and, if it's a match, don't do your special logic.

Probably the easiest way to do that is to use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest), e.g.:

```
$(document).keydown(function (evt) {
    if (!$(evt.target).closest('input, select, textarea')[0]) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 78) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            scrollToNew();
        } else if (evt.keyCode == 80) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            scrollToLast();
        }
    }
});
```

There I'm asking what the closest form field is starting with the element (since `closest` starts with the element you give it) and working up through ancestors. If there are non, then the returned jQuery object will be empty, and `[0]` will return `undefined`. So since `!undefined` is `true`, we'll process your logic when *not* in a form field.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like

```
$('form').on('keydown', function(event) {event.stopPropagation();});
```

should do the trick if you don't need keyboard controls from inside of a form.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `target` property of the [`Event` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event), which points to the source DOM node. So, you could easily use

```
var nn = evt.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
if (nn != "input" && nn != "textarea")
    // do your special handling
```

but it might be easier to check for existance of the [`form` property](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#dom-fae-form), which points to elements owner form:

```
if (! "form" in evt.target)
    // do your special handling
```